# Advance manual unpivot of data table

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to transform a table in a very particular way, kind of pivoting in the timestamps but maintaining the data structure of all the other columns. Here's what I mean:

[image]

As you can see is kind of unpivoting the table but I can't figure out how to keep the desired structure and also considering there are hundreds of rows and columns.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: What's the reason for keeping a column for each Milestone? The Milestone is already defined by the row. If there's no actual reason for this, I think the answer referenced by @a-burge can work for your situation.

Comment: for the purposes of the visualization I need to create, the milestone needs to appear. But is all good, the answer in the other question with some FILTER solved it. Thanks!